# How to delete Terraform module reference if provider declared in module?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am attempting to delete a module in which I have a providers block, shown below, specifying a non-hashicorp provider. From my understanding, non hashicorp providers are not inherited because when running Terraform it would explicitly complain about not finding a 'hashicorp/azuredevops' provider.

```
# Defined in module
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.13"

  required_providers {
    azuredevops = {
      source = "microsoft/azuredevops"
      version = ">= 0.1.0"
    }
  }
}
```

My root configuration contains a provider block similar to the following:

```
# Defined in root
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.13"

  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 3.19.1"
    }
    azuredevops = {
      source  = "microsoft/azuredevops"
      version = ">= 0.1.0"
    }
  }
}
```

I can create a module successfully:

```
module "example" {
  source           = "../modules/example/"
  application_name = "example"
  location         = var.location
  environment      = var.environment
}
```

But when I attempt to delete it by commenting it out, I get the error mentioned at the beginning of the post.

How can I have the module inherit the microsoft provider from the root so I can successfully delete this specific module reference?

```
│ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│ 
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider
│ hashicorp/azuredevops: provider registry registry.terraform.io does not
│ have a provider named registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azuredevops
```

Edit:

Providers from `terraform providers`

```
Providers required by configuration:
.
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm]
└── module.example
    ├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azuredevops]

Providers required by state:

    provider[registry.terraform.io/microsoft/azuredevops]

    provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm]
```

Comment: If you run `terraform providers`, Terraform should explain where it found the requirement for each provider that `terraform init` would try to install. Can you run that and then edit your question to include the output?

Comment: I have updated the question with the output from the 'terraform providers' command

Comment: If you have removed the `module "example"` block then I wouldn't expect to see `module.example` mentioned in that output. Can you confirm that you removed that block (or, equivalently, commented it out) before you ran this command?

Comment: If I comment all the references to this shared module it will initialize successfully. But I want to somehow change the reference of the provider to the root level rather than the module. Is that possible?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not really sure what you are asking. You seem to already have a configuration which correctly declares that `module.example` depends on both `hashicorp/azurerm` and `microsoft/azuredevops`. There is nothing to change here: you configuration is already correct.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. The issue was I could not destroy module.example, referencing a shared module, because the module.example was referencing the provider declared in the shared module. Chicken/egg problem I suppose. So what I did was (Disclaimer, the following can be super risky!) I edited the state file and any "provider": "module.example.provider[\"registry.terraform.io/microsoft/azuredevops\"]" I changed to "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/microsoft/azuredevops\"]" which now references the root level declared provider

Comment: One thing to note, if it's a third party provider, you'll have to declare the reference even in the module. I had to explicitly add terraform {
  required_providers {
    azuredevops = {
      source = "microsoft/azuredevops"
    }
  }
}
 to the shared module even though I also declared it in the root level provider configuration, e.g. terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.13"
  required_providers {
    azuredevops = {
      source  = "microsoft/azuredevops"
      version = ">= 0.1.0"
    } 
}
}
. Now I can create module, then destroy it after since it refs the root provider

Comment: Oh, okay... the problem you encountered is something separate from what you asked about. A child module should generally never contain a `provider` block, because then as you've seen it becomes impossible to remove the module in a single step. Terraform's documentation recommends against doing that but Terraform continues to allow it anyway because there are existing configurations relying on this capability, which are working as long as nobody ever tries to remove the child module.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the `required_providers` block in the child module. It's the `provider "azuredevops"` block that was the problem, but I wasn't able to guess that because you didn't include it in your question.

Comment: Absolutely and sorry for the confusion! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi @Kevys if the solution provided was helpful, please incorporate it as an answer to help the SO community.

Answer (score 1):

This concerns the `provider` block inside the child module, which is required, but cannot be found once the module is commented out. See this comment from [hashicorp](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/develop/providers):

> As a consequence, you must ensure that all resources that belong to a
> particular provider configuration are destroyed before you can remove
> that provider configuration's block from your configuration. If
> Terraform finds a resource instance tracked in the state whose
> provider configuration block is no longer available then it will
> return an error during planning, prompting you to reintroduce the
> provider configuration.

See also a two-step proposed solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50856192/cannot-delete-an-instance-of-module-in-terraform-which-contains-a-provider?rq=4).

A better way to define providers is to remove any `provider` blocks from any modules, and only keep a `required_providers` inside the module.

This way you can pass the provider from your root into the child module, like so:

```
module "test" {
  source       = "./module/working"
  project_name = local.project_name
  env_name     = local.env_name1
  providers = {
    azuredevops = azuredevops.test
  }
}
```

If you would comment out the `providers` argument in this module call you will get the same error as before when trying to destroy the module. Note that when you implement this, make sure that all resources using the old provider config are removed, otherwise you get the same error again.

A full example:

[image]

`main.tf` in root:

```
locals {
  azuredevops_pat = <your PAT>
  org_service_url = <url of project, e.g. https://dev.azure.com/some_name>
  project_name    = <name of azdo project>
  env_name1       = "Example Environment 1"
  env_name2       = "Example Environment 2"
}

terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.13"

  required_providers {
    azuredevops = {
      source  = "microsoft/azuredevops"
      version = ">= 0.1.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azuredevops" {
  personal_access_token = local.azuredevops_pat
  org_service_url       = local.org_service_url
  alias                 = "test"
}

module "test" {
  source       = "./module/working"
  project_name = local.project_name
  env_name     = local.env_name1
  providers = {
    azuredevops = azuredevops.test
  }
}

module "test2" {
  source       = "./module/failing"
  project_name = local.project_name
  env_name     = local.env_name2
}
```

`main.tf` in module/working:

```
terraform {
    required_providers {
        azuredevops = {
        source = "microsoft/azuredevops"
        }
    }
}

variable "project_name" {
  type = string
}
variable "env_name" {
  type = string
}

data "azuredevops_project" "example" {
    name = var.project_name
}

resource "azuredevops_environment" "example" {
    project_id = data.azuredevops_project.example.id
    name       = var.env_name
}
```

`main.tf` in module/failing:

```
locals {
  azuredevops_pat = <pat>
  org_service_url = <url>
}

provider "azuredevops" {
  personal_access_token = local.azuredevops_pat
  org_service_url       = local.org_service_url
}

terraform {
    required_providers {
        azuredevops = {
        source = "microsoft/azuredevops"
        }
    }
}

variable "project_name" {
  type = string
}
variable "env_name" {
  type = string
}

data "azuredevops_project" "example" {
    name = var.project_name
}

resource "azuredevops_environment" "example" {
    project_id = data.azuredevops_project.example.id
    name       = var.env_name
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed example. This makes perfect sense!